# Flair NLP package on cloud TPU

Tags: nlp, cloud, tpu, flair

Is it possible to use "flair" nlp library on Google cloud TPU ? I am trying to use Google Colab runtime TPUs and getting some errors.

Comment: What errors are you getting? Please edit your answer and add some of your code.

Comment: When I am run it on my local anaconda jupyter notebook it runs without error but when Im using google colab tpu it gives me 
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0a0+d6149a7'

Comment: from flair.embeddings import FlairEmbeddings, BertEmbeddings

# init Flair embeddings
flair_forward_embedding = FlairEmbeddings('multi-forward')

Answer (score 0):

I found that if i change version to 1.5 this error goes away, due to wrong typecasting in the code. However, it still seems to get stuck .. not sure why.. whereas on GPU it works fine.